# Why Pycharm doesn't understand which parameters to pass to an inherited Python dataclass' __init__?

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm

Why doesn't Pycharm understand which parameters to pass to the **init** of a subclass in the case of dataclasses

**Additional information following comments on the question: I am using Pycharm *2018.3.4 Community* edition with Python 3.7.3**

I have the following code in Python:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class A():
    r: int
    s: int

@dataclass
class B(A):
    t: int

    @staticmethod
    def agg(r: int, s: int, t: int):
        record: B = B(r,s,t)
        return record

b: B = B.agg(1,22,333)
print(b)
```

which results in the following output:

```
B(r=1, s=22, t=333)
```

However, Pycharm fails to understand which parameters should be passed to B's **init** when dataclasses are involved.
Pycharm works just fine when you write your own **init** methods.

**What am I doing wrong here?
How to make Pycharm display the correct help?**

---

**Pycharm shows the list of parameters to provide to __init__**

[image: Pycharm shows the list of parameters to provide to __init__]

---

**Pycharm doesn't show the list of parameters to provide to __init__**

[image: Pycharm doesn't show the list of parameters to provide to __init__]

Comment: Looks like a bug/feature? What are the folks over at JetBrains saying?

Comment: [This bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34566) (listed as a duplicate of [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28506)) is marked as fixed in version `2019.1`. Which version are you running?

Comment: Make sure to use the latest version. It works ok in 2019.2.5.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 2018.3.4 Community edition. I will try and update you on the result.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Pycharm 2019.2.5 shows the correct hints for all the parameters from both dataclasses

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the question's comments.

Upgrade of Pycharm community edition from version 2018.3.4 to 2019.2.5, solved the issue.

[image: Latest Pycharm 2019.2.5 shows the correct hints for inherited dataclasses]